# using relative path on .nuget packages folder in .csproj file

Tags: c#, nuget-package

How to use relative path on .nuget packages folder in .csproj file. I've .txt content files and it is copied to my bin directory if I make a build only if I set the property to copy always. By doing that I see a full hardcoded path value (c:\users\usr1234.nuget\packages\packagename\contentfiles\any\newfile.txt) in my .csproj file 
how to set the relative path in my .csproj file or is there any work around for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove some content files from my solution and the output directory. I did it by including the following in my `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\your.package\*\contentFiles\any\somefile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- `$(UserProfile)` corresponds to `C:\\users\YourUsername`
- `\*\` is
  used to be able to exclude files from differnet versions of your
  nuget package so you don't need to update this line when you update
  your nuget package to a new version

**Also I'm not sure this will work outside Windows**